# Horizontal stacked-bar charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to make a stacked bar chart that goes from left to right. Right now, I'm having some issues with how the spacing and such would go, since I'm not really familiar with the graphing system on computers.

Here's my code:

```
var canvas = d3.select("#canvas");
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;

//rectangle values
var values = [{
    cValue: Math.abs(xthree),
    color: '#A0F'
}, {
    cValue: Math.abs(xtwo),
    color: '#FA0'
}, {
    cValue: Math.abs(xone),
    color: '#0AF'
}, {
    cValue: Math.abs(xzero),
    color: '#AF0'
}];

//var colours = ['#A0F', '#FA0', '#0AF', '#AF0'];

var yOffset = 0;

//create scale
//yRange2 = d3.scale.linear().range([canvas.height - MARGINS.top,
//MARGINS.bottom]).domain([0, 10]);

//yrange2- imp-Set domain to be set to biggest number
yRange2 = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 10])
    .range([MARGINS.bottom, canvas.height - MARGINS.top]);

//Process the data

for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

    var datum = {

        value: yRange2(values[i].cValue),
        colour: values[i].color,
        y: 0,
        x: yOffset

    }

    yOffset += (canvas.height - MARGINS.top - datum.value);

    data.push(datum)
}

//setup y
yAxis2 = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yRange2)
    .tickSize(5)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickSubdivide(true);

canvas.append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (3 * MARGINS.bottom) + ")")
    .call(yAxis2);

var bars = canvas.selectAll('rect').data(data)

var cumValues = 0;
bars
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr("class", "myBars" + function (d) {
        return d.colour;
    })
    .attr({
        height: 30,
        y: 20,
        x: function (d) {
            return d.value - d.x; <-----------------------------------
        },
        width: function (d) {
            return canvas.width - MARGINS.left - d.value; <-----------
        }
    })
    .style({
        fill: function (d) {
            return d.colour
        }
    });
```

Right now, I'm having problems with the way that the rectangles would be placed, which I've highlighted in the code.

[Here's the full code](http://jsfiddle.net/ehv6fb1L/3/)

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/datashaman/rBfy5/4/light/

Comment: I was actually looking at this one already, coincidentially enough. The only problem I have with it though is that I can't seem to make sense of it's logic

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Yeah, I tried it in http://jsfiddle.net/ehv6fb1L/4/ and it didn't work very well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equations that lead to the property definitions have to be completely redefined. I used the following, which worked perfectly:

```
     for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

        var datum = {

            value: yRange2(values[i].cValue),
            colour: values[i].color,
            y: 0,
            x: yOffset

        }

        yOffset += (datum.value);
        data.push(datum)
    }
```

---

```
.attr({
        height: 30,
        y: 20,
        x: function (d) {
            return barMARGINS.left + d.x;
        },
        width: function (d) {
            return d.value;
        }
    })
```